# Is causing oneself to have an erection forbidden or just not recommended?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, sexuality, maseches-niddah

In the [Mishneh Torah Hilchos Issurei Biah 21:19](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960669/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twenty-One.htm) it says:

> It is forbidden for a person to intentionally cause himself to have an erection or to bring himself to [sexual] thoughts.

Yet in [Niddah 13b](http://www.come-and-hear.com/niddah/niddah_13.html#chapter_ii) it says:

> Rab stated: 'A man who wilfully causes erection should be placed under the ban'. But why did he not say, 'This is forbidden'? Because the man merely incites his evil inclination against himself.

So it seems that the Rambam classifies it as forbidden, yet the Talmud seems to say it's not (explicitly) "forbidden."

Comment: `"merely incites..."` The translator added "merely." The implication of the gemara appears to be the opposite of what the translator wrote; not only is it forbidden, but there would also be a requirement to put the person in *nidui* if he is found to do this (see [*Tosafos*, s.v. "המקשה"](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=13b&format=text), who maintains that a person is not automatically in *nidui* for this behavior). The [*Chasam Sofer* (ad loc.)](https://books.google.com/books?id=9S8vAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false) expressly reads the passage this way.

Comment: there are other gemoras which sound even worse than the rambam such as http://www.come-and-hear.com/niddah/niddah_13.html

Comment: @ray that's the same daf as quoted in the question

Comment: @Fred I haven't read the Chasam Sofer, but that sounds like a chiddush, i.e i dont think anyone else before holds that as pashat

Comment: @jj2 IMHO, the Chasam Sofer (and, apparently, the Rambam) flows with the gemara and fits with the subsequent statement of R' Ami that this person is called a "transgressor." I suppose the gemara could also be read the way you say: R' Ami could be seen as a dissenting opinion, especially since his opinion is introduced with "ורבי אמי אמר". Or perhaps R' Ami doesn't even mean that it is a sin, just that he is called a "transgressor" because that activity tends to lead to actual sin. But do you know of anyone (aside from Rabbi Epstein who translated this) who expressly reads the passage this way?

Comment: @Fred that's the literal translation, leima asur (say that it is forbidden)

Comment: @jj2 That's the translation, but it doesn't necessarily imply that "יהא בנדוי" and "אסור" are mutually exclusive, or that "אסור" is more severe than "יהא בנדוי". The question could be motivated by the assumption that "יהא בנדוי" is more severe than "אסור", and the gemara might be asking why it says "יהא בנדוי" rather than just "אסור". Or, per the Chasam Sofer, the question is motivated by the assumption that both categories are equivalent (see Shulchan Aruch YD 334:1), and the answer is that "יהא בנדוי" in this context implies it is אסור but even more severe than typical נדוי liability.

Comment: @jj2 its amud aleph. there it says "one who touches himself (even for medical purposes) brings destruction to the world

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, note that the Maharal and Maharsha (and I would assume others) consider this Gemara to be Agadic and not Halachic, as they put it in their Chiddushei Agados. Thus, it could very likely that this is a plain Issur, and this Gemara just adds "Agadic warning" to this Aveirah.

Secondly, the Poskim (Shulchan Aruch, Aruch Hashulchan EH 23:3) seem to quote the wording of the Rambam that it is Assur, so "it is forbidden".

Thirdly, there are other opinions in the Gemara there that consider such a person an "Avaryan", which clearly indicates that it is an Aveirah, and that could be the source of Rambam. (h/t to Fred)

Fourthly, the major source of discussion is Ran to Rif Shabbos 39b, who says:

> אלא ודאי לישנא דיהא בנדוי היינו לומר שראוי לנדותו והיינו דפרכינן הכא ולימא אסור כלומר ובהכי משמע שראוי לנדותו שכך הוא המדה בכל האיסורים שהעובר עליהן ראוי לנדותו ופרקינן דנקט כי האי לישנא לאשמועינן שאיסורו יותר מפני שמגרה יצה"ר בעצמו:‏

The "Chavrusa" Gemara and Shu"t Amudei Eish understands this Ran that it is more Chamur to say Nidui than to say Assur, and that Issur is included in Nidui, nit that it is only a Niddui and No Issur. See also Aruch Laner and Chasam Sofer there who learn similarly (although the Aruch Laner has a bit of a twist), h/t to commenters who pointed them out.

Fifthly, see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24329&st=&pgnum=101) for a very strange interpretation of what the phrase "Veleima Assur" means והדבר פלא.

Sixthly, there is a huge discussion of how Rambam understands and applies this Gemara.  See Issurei Biah 21:19, Talmud Torah 6:14, and a boatload of Mefarshim in those places, as well as here in Niddah, who discuss his Shitah.  Some (see Divrei Chamudos here in Niddah and others) say that he doesn't even consider someone to be in Nidui unless they are actually Motzi Zera Levatalah, although I believe that everyone holds that it is Assur.

Answer (score -2):

Tomer Devorah [ch.8](http://www.digital-brilliance.com/kab/deborah/chap8.htm)

> Now, just as the Supernal Bow is never stretched except it be toward
>   this target, so, too, man should not stretch his bow and allow himself
>   and erection under any circumstances except it be for the proper
>   purpose, namely, for his wife when she is clean, which is the time of
>   union. And not more than this, for it causes a flaw in this quality (of netzach),
>   God forfend. Exceedingly great care must be taken and the main
>   precaution is to guard oneself from sexual imaginings

seems then that it is forbidden. only that we are not angels so it's not a clear cut transgression like eating non-kosher food.

Comment: The question cited two earlier works that seemed to contradict one another as to whether it's forbidden. You cited a further source supporting one side but I don't see how that answers the question. If one wants a source supporting one side or the other, it's in the question already; what's wanted here is not that but something that resolves or explains away the contradiction.

Comment: (continued) This is not entirely your fault, since the question's title sounds like it's asking a plain question of fact (not a contradiction) and the question itself (which mentions the contradiction) has no actual question in it. It's rather poorly written.

Comment: @msh210 agreed. tried to make the best of the two

Answer (score -2):

Giluy arayos generally is an aveirah bein adam le'atzmo.

Therefore being makshe atzmo le'daas is more repugnant than assur.

However chazal have the ability to be menadeh people who behave repugnantly personally.

Comment: So you're saying that it's not forbidden?

Comment: You should expand on this and explain what you mean with sources.